# ios touch location without uigesturerecognizer

Tags: ios, uiview, touch, uiwindow

How to get touch location on uiwindow or uiview without uigesturerecognizer,
purpose is getting touch location in extremely low latency as dispatcher can delay touch firing events

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass `UIView` and override the `UIResponder` (superclass of `UIView`) method `touchesBegan(_:with:)`. See the docs for the method [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan).

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        // Get the touch location in THIS VIEW's coordinate system:
        let locationInThisView = touch.location(in: self)

        // Get the touch location in the WINDOW's coordinate system
        let locationInWindow = touch.location(in: nil)
    }
}
```

Also, make sure your view has the property `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `true`.

Comment: when i override touchesBegan i still need to wait until the dispatcher fires touchesBegan event,in my personal tests it is fired with 50Hz,with some delay, but i want to get it 100Hz,with low latency

Comment: As far as I know, the iOS SDK does not offer anything faster. Perhaps if you subclass `UIWindow` instead (the root object of the view hierarchy), it will be called slightly sooner?

Comment: Perhaps overrding `UIApplication.sendEvent()`? Can't think of anything else. Either way, `touchesBegan(...` is fast enough that interactivity feels natural to human users. I wonder what your app is trying to do that needs to detect taps in such real time conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Override the below method in your *UIView* subclass.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let point =  touches.first?.location(in: self)
    print("location: ", point ?? CGPoint.zero)
}
```

Comment: when i override touchesBegan i still need to wait until the dispatcher fires touchesBegan event,in my personal tests it is fired with 50Hz,with some delay, but i want to get it 100Hz,with low latency